# egrep for time in H:MM:SS format

Tags: bash, regex, grep, egrep

Working on the file an need to grep the line with a time stamp in the H:MM:SS format.
I tried the following egrep '[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]'. Didn't work for me. What am i doing wrong in regex?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file you are running this on, what you expect to get, and what you are getting instead? It is much easier to diagnose a regex if we can see the data and have an understanding of your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to match for
00:00:00 to 23:59:59

```
egrep '([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'t
```

if you want to match for
12:00 pm to 12:59 am

```
egrep -i '((?:0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s?(?:a|p)m)'
```

Comment: For the 2nd one, change `[0-1][0-2]` to `(0[0-9]|1[012])` which introduces the edge cases of times > "12:00:00"

Comment: in fact [0-1][0-2] will match for 00 to 12, since [0-1] will match for 0 or 1 not both, and [0-2] will match for 0 or 2 not both
so [0-1][0-2] will match for [0-1] -> 0 [0-2] -> 0 = 00:00:00
or [0-1] -> 1 [0-2] -> 2 = 12:00:00

Comment: Well, does that regex match 03:00:00am?

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, i figured out, that mistake, Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]` would match H:M:S, bot not H:MM:SS.

Each set of square brackets matches a single character.

So to get something that matches H:MM:SS you could use:

`[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`

Note, the above will NOT match H:M:S

In order to match H:MM:SS OR H:M:S OR H:M:SS OR H:MM:S use the following

`[0-9]:[0-9]+:[0-9]+`

`+` means match the last character, 1 or more times (including the first match)

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I remember `.` matches ANY character. Not the last one again. That means, that `[0-9].` matches `5a` and `7-` and also `33`. And you don’t need to escape `:` (it has no regex meaning). Therefore: Your answer is not correct.

Comment: My bad! You are correct sir. Editing now... Is there no repetition symbol to repeat once and only once? (I can't find one, so I'm thinking the best way is `[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: I don’t know of any repetition symbol (this is not vim). I use `{NUMBER}` to request a specific `NUMBER` of repetitions, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use

```
egrep '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'
```

where `{2}` means match last character at least two times and maximum two times (= exactly two times), where last character in this example was a number between 0 and 9.

If you want to search for it least one and maximum two you have to change it to

```
egrep '[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}'
```

which matches for example on `0:1:22` and `0:11:22` and `00:11:22` and `00:11:2` and so on.

The answer Sirius_Black gave is also testing on real times. My answer would match for unrealistic times like 99:99:99 – which could however be a time duration.